# Change Facebook App ID for React-Native-FBSDK iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, fbsdk

Using `react-native run-ios` the application would not recognize the new Facebook App ID.

I had to change the Facebook App ID for a react-native project I'm working on. I changed the App ID everywhere it says {your-app-id} in Info.plist according to the getting started as well as the {your-app-name}. After that, I did a `SHIFT+COMMAND+K` to clear the build folder and built/ran the application in Xcode. So when I run in Xcode, the application uses the new Facebook App ID, but if I use the react native cli to run ios project, it uses the old ID.

Does anyone know whats causing this? Thanks

Comment: did you find an answer to this? I have the same issue.